# Passing String[] to Adapter but output is not showing

Tags: android, adapter

I am passing the **String[]** and image into **Adapter** class which the image grid.
Please check my code and let me know where should be the error because I am not getting any error and output. As program is working of I set the **String[]** in the same Adapter class :(

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String[] mThumbIds = {
        "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/img/1.gif",
        "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/img/1.gif",
        "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/img/1.gif",
        "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/img/1.gif",
        "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/img/1.gif",
        "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/img/1.gif",
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter (MainActivity.this);
    imageAdapter.setimag(mThumbIds,mThumbIds.length);

    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            //   i.putExtra("id", position);
            //   startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    int imageTotal;
    public static String[] mThumbIds;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public void setimag(String[] mThumbIds,int count){
        this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
        this.imageTotal = count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageTotal;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480, 480));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        String url = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loader)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop().into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Please help me out As I am new in android :(

Comment: As a side note, you should not need to pass the `count` into `setimag()` and neither the existence of the field `imageTotal` in the adapter. You can use `mThumbIds.length` inside the Adapter in `getCount()`.

Comment: But why the program is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you are going wrong `gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));` , instead of passing the initialized adapter you are passing new adapter which has no image id's.

corrected code

```
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter (MainActivity.this);
imageAdapter.setimag(mThumbIds,mThumbIds.length);

final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much

Comment: you must have a light tick button below my answer upvotes count.